# Add triggers to table using migrations - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

I've seen a few answers to this question but none of them work, and none of them were for 5.1

This is my migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        DB::unprepared('
            USE `widatdb`;
            DELIMITER $$
            CREATE TRIGGER `topics_AUPD` BEFORE UPDATE ON `topics` FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN
                IF (NEW.abstract <> OLD.abstract)
                THEN
                    SET NEW.got_updated = 1;
                END IF;
            END
        ');
    }
```

If I introduce a syntax error in the trigger declaration, its error will be shown during migration. But right now, after running `php artisan migrate` ( which gets finished without any errors ), the trigger is not added to the table.
Any idea?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it worked for me:

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    DB::getPdo()->exec('
        CREATE TRIGGER `users_BUPD` BEFORE UPDATE ON `users` FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            IF (NEW.score <> OLD.score)
            THEN
                INSERT INTO `score_history` VALUES(NULL, OLD.id, OLD.score, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
            END IF;
        END
    ');
}
```